# TypeScript: How to use const assertions to function's parameter

Tags: typescript, types, constants

How can I use const assertions for function's parameter? Or create new variable and set its value = bars as const

```
function foo(bars: string[]) {
    // Some code here
    const constBars = bars as const
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve specifically? Are you trying to make it so that the array cannot be rewritten by the code?

Comment: @ExplosionPills,I am trying to generate a typed Record where keys are value from bars

Answer (score 0):

You can assert that the parameters must be an array of values contained within a const assertion.

Create the const assertion and generic type (`ConstType` in this example) that will allow only keys and values from the given generic:

```
const BarArg = {
  red: 'red',
  blue: 'blue',
  yellow: 'yellow'
} as const;

export type ConstType<T> = T[keyof T];

function foo(bar: ConstType<BarArg>[]) { ... }
```

Then, you'll be able to invoke the function with the string literals contained within `BarArg` or with references to its properties.

```
foo(['red', 'yellow']);
```

or

```
foo([BarArgs.red, BarArgs.yellow]);
```

Unlike enums, const assertions can contain more than strings and numbers which makes them very useful when asserting objects contain functions and/or objects as values.

All that being said, unless you really need the const assertion for some reason, it would be simpler to just create a type for those known arguments specifically. Something like:

```
type BarArg = 'red' | 'blue' | 'yellow';

function foo(bar: BarArg[]) {}
```

Or, just utilize an enum:

```
enum BarArg = {
  Red = 'red',
  Blue = 'blue',
  Yellow = 'yellow'
}

function foo(bar: BarArg[]) { }
```